# Highlight cells until sum of another cell is met

Tags: microsoft-excel, conditional-formatting

On the attached image, I want to highlight the cells automatically that equal **branch IBT** sum until sum is met.

[image]

Example 1 - **Leic & scun** would be highlighted because they are the first two columns that sum to the branch IBT value of 2.
Example 2 - **Lough** would be highlighted because it is the first column that sums to the branch IBT value of 1.

How can I do this with conditional formatting?

Comment: I don’t understand. Please add more detail to your words and, ideally, upload a better image (try to get the width to be ≤ 660 pixels).

Comment: Sorry, branch IBT column is the sum (total amount) for part  ( PPFCAL9234R) I would like column LEIC & SCUN to be highlighted as they can have 1 each and the Branch IBT = 2

Comment: for part number (PPFCAL9006R-GRN) branch IBT = 1 ,,, so I would like LOUGH to be highlighted as this is the next available columns that have a '1' with LOUGH  having one this  equals  the branch IBT column.. hope this helps . thank you

Comment: Sorry, but I still don’t get it.  If you really want help with this, then please [edit] your question to show exactly what calculations and comparisons lead to the decision to highlight or not highlight each cell.  Explain the red marks.  Is the image you have posted intended to show the highlighting results that you want?  If so, explain why the penultimate cell in the Scun column (i.e., the one in the PPFCAL9213L row) isn’t highlighted (and, for that matter, why the Lough column isn’t highlighted). … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  If the image you have posted does not show the highlighting results that you want, then upload one that does — keeping the width ≤ 660 pixels, and including the column and row labels, so we can talk about cell `G5` instead of talking about “the penultimate cell in the Scun column (i.e., the one in the PPFCAL9213L row)”.  Don’t say “Example 1” and “Example 2” unless you *show* an “Example 1” and “Example 2”.  Do you want cells in the PPFCAL9234R row to be highlighted?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a single conditional formatting rule. Select all your data in the location columns (i.e., Leic, Scun, Lough, etc.) and click `Conditional Formatting` > `New Rule...` on the Home ribbon. Choose `Use a formula to determine which cells to format`, and enter this formula (adjust to match your data of course).

```
=AND(SUM($E2:E2)<=$B2,E2<>0)
```

Where E2 is the top-left cell of the selection and B2 is the desired total for the first row.

Set your desired format and click OK.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Okay, this can be done and if you set the top row up correctly, you can copy and paste down the columns, saving you some time.

The first thing here is that you'll need to set up 2 rules.  One is to conditionally format with the information you need above, the other is to change the formatting if the cell value changes to 0.

Firstly select the very first cell with a number in it under Lei then on the Home tab, click Conditional Formatting -> New Rule.  In the box that opens, select "Use a formula to determine which cells for format"

In the formula box, type what I have but substitute correct cell references you are using.

[image: Initial formula]

Choose your chosen formatting and click okay.

Now it's time for the second rule:  Go to Conditional Formatting -> Highlights Cells Rules -> Equal To

In the box that appears, change the default entry to 0 and format how you want it to appear if there is no stock.

Finally, go to Conditional Formatting -> Manage Rules, select the and next to the Cell Value = 0 rule, click the tickbox Stop If True and click OK to close the box.

This will cover you for the entire first column so you can now copy and paste down the whole thing.

With the next column, you need to change the formula as follows:
[image: Second formula for more than one column]

Again, add the second formula for if the cell value = 0 and the Stop If True tickbox and that should cover you for the second column.

Repeat across all columns, amending the second part of the SUM formula to show the last cell that should be checked.

If all is working correctly, you can go from something like this:
[image: First example]

To this with a change of a figure or two.
[image: Second example]